# How to configure IIS 10 to forward requests to web apps

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy

I want **IIS 10** to redirect requests to several other web apps (ASP.NET Core 6.0 and Angular 14) 
Let's say I have Kestrel listening on http://localhost:5009/ serving one of those apps, I want to type

```
http://localhost/PassThrough/
```

into browser address and to have it redirected to

```
http://localhost:5171/
```

And also

```
http://localhost/PassThrough/todo/param1
```

to

```
http://localhost:5171/todo/param1
```

**UPDATE**:

Tried a rewrite URL method suggested by @TengFeiXie
[image]

[image]

and a bunch of variants. None of it worked.
The problem with this method I think is IIS will only allow you to match a pattern after the first / and if you rewrite the matched part it will not add port in the correct place (before the first /).
Redirect will also not redirect correctly for the same reason.

The second suggestion - reverse proxy also did not bare fruit:
Both

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Reverse Proxy to webmail" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^PassThrough/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5171/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

and

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Reverse Proxy to webmail" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="http://localhost/PassThrough/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5171/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

in web.config
end up redirecting to

```
http://localhost/localhost:5171
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:5171
```

So same issue basically in both suggestions. It boils down to setting up the rule. If you are able to provide the rule that works let's say in xml form I'd be happy to test it.

Latest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="PassThrough" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="http://localhost/PassThrough(/(.*))*" />
                        <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:5171{R:1}" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS provides official components, **URL Redirection** or **Reverse Proxy** both can meet your needs.

1. Get the URL Rewrite module:
   https://iis-umbraco.azurewebsites.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite.
   You can refer to the steps in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) to
   create redirect rules, redirect from http://localhost/App1/ to
   http://localhost:5009/.
2. Reverse Proxy needs Application Request Routing:
   https://iis-umbraco.azurewebsites.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing.

   Configuring Rules for the Reverse Proxy:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing#configuring-rules-for-the-reverse-proxy.

The official documentation for URL redirection and reverse proxy has detailed steps and reference examples.

**Update:**

OK, It seems you are not familiar with rewrite rules. I'll demonstrate the steps to go from **http://localhost/PassThrough/**  to  **http://localhost:5171/**. You'll find it's really easy.

I have an *article.html* on port 5174.

[image]

Then I added the following inbound rules in **Default Web Site**（port 80）.

[image]

In Web.config

```
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxy" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="passthrough/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5171/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
```

Request: **http://localhost/PassThrough/article.html**. Successfully got the  *article.html*.

[image]

Comment: Please see the Update on the question for the results of me following up on all your links. If you have specific regular expression or xml rule for either case that will do what I need, please post

Comment: Your update is one of the combinations I tried. And it did not work. In fact the second one I listed in my answer should have worked according to what you say. Does your case work when listening on port 5171 is not another IIS website but instead and ASP.NET Core 6.0 application hosted in Kestrel and serving something other than a static file?

Comment: I finally figured out what my problem was after many many tries. It was caching. Browser caching errors. I had to start an incognito window to catch that. I would only suggest changing your pattern from passthrough/(.*) to passthrough(/(.*))* to not require / at the end of passthrough